# Apply query in elasticsearch to get true/false value without filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

I have got this kind of mapping on my ES index

```
    {
  "vabaco_dhp_development_persons" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "person" : {
        "properties" : {
          "active" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "booking_resources" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "available_days" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "available_date" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                  },
                  "last_slot_time" : {
                    "type" : "date"
                  }
                }
              },
              "booking_resource_detail" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "from_age" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  },
                  "to_age" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              },
              "booking_resource_price" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "booking_resource_restriction" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "insurer_restrictions" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "insurer_ic" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "booking_resource_service_restrictions" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "insurance_service_code" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                  },
                  "insurer_provider_ic" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                  },
                  "location_id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "city_id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "doctor_languages" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "language_id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  }
                }
              },
              "doctor_speciality" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "location" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "address" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "brand_name" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "district" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "user_profile_city" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "searchable_text" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "en" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "ka" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "fields" : {
                      "keyword" : {
                        "type" : "keyword",
                        "ignore_above" : 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "service_provision_type" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "id" : {
                    "type" : "integer"
                  },
                  "id_name" : {
                    "type" : "text"
                  },
                  "name" : {
                    "properties" : {
                      "en" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "ka" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" : 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "covid_19" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "first_name" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ka" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ka" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "person_star" : {
            "properties" : {
              "avg" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "disable_rating" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "star_count" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "priority_city" : {
            "properties" : {
              "id" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "object"
              },
              "priority" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "uuid" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "views" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to apply query to filter based on "booking_resource_service_restrictions" field, but in some cases I just need to know if this query, if applied, would filter particular record, which means I need to get some true/false value for every record, based on this filter(but data should not be filtered), is there any way to extract this kind of information for every record?
sample query looks like this, this is how I filter data based on "booking_resource_service_restrictions" filed but as I already mentioned in some cases I want to know if this filter would work if applied and get true/false values for every record without actually filtering them

```
GET vabaco_dhp_development_persons/_search
{
  "query": {
   "bool":{
      "must":[
          {
            "term":{
               "active": true
            }
         },
         {
            "nested":{
               "path":"booking_resources",
               "query":{
                  "bool":{
                     "must":[
                        {
                           "nested":{
                              "path":"booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions",
                              "query":{
                                 "bool":{
                                    "should":[
                                       {
                                          "bool":{
                                             "must":[
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.insurer_provider_ic":"204919008"
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.insurance_service_code":"11111"
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                  {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.location_id": 1
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       },
                                       {
                                          "bool":{
                                             "must":[
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.insurer_provider_ic":"204919008"
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.insurance_service_code":"33333"
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                  {
                                                   "term":{
                                                      "booking_resources.booking_resource_service_restrictions.location_id": 1
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ],
                                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
}
```

In general what I need is a way to know if record a satisfies some filtering requirements and base on this get true/false values(or data equivalent to true/false)

Answer (score 1):

You can use named queries to give names to your queries and filters using "_name" field.
Add your query in a should clause so that it does not affect the documents returned.

When you search, you need to look for "matched_queries" array in the result to find names of all queries matched for that particular document.

```
{
      "_index": "testindex",
      "_type": "employee",
      "_id": "2",
      "_score": 0.19178301,
      "_source": {
        "name": "Barkha Jain"
      },
      "matched_queries": [
        "query on name field"
      ]
    }
```

Read about named queries here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/query-dsl-bool-query.html#named-queries